# How to cite author-date including page number in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am using `org-ref` in `org-mode`. I want to cite a book like this:

```
    \citep[p. 1445]{Fong:2006}
```

but I am only getting `citep:Fong:2006`. How can I include page number?

Answer (score 4):

`[[citep:Fong:2006][p. 1445]]` is exported to latex as `\citep[p. 1445]{Fong:2006}`

Comment: To do this in a repeatable way, also see John Kitchin's answer. TL:DR use `C-c C-l` and you can enter the page number as a description which will format the square brackets for you. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/52498/24053