# How do you create an org-ref harvard style in-text citation - with a page number - using shortcuts?

Tags: org-mode, org-ref

There are only really two kinds of citations I need to have in my paper

1. `(Lewis, 2001)`
2. `(Lewis, 2001:54)` where 54 is the page number

After a ton of googling I managed to find out that it's possible to create  both these kinds of citations with `org-ref` in `org-mode` [[1]](https://nickgeorge.net/science/org_ref_setup/) [[2]](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19570/how-to-cite-author-date-including-page-number-in-org-mode)

For a minimal example:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[round]{natbib}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setcitestyle{notesep={:}}

* Test
1. This is an author year citation citep:lewis_plurality_2001
2. This has a page number [[cite:lewis_plurality_2001][100]]

bibliographystyle:apalike
bibliography:bibliography.bib
```

Will create:

> 1. This is an author year citation (Lewis, 2001)
> 2. This has a page number (Lewis, 2001:100)

But as noted in *[How to cite author-date including page number in org-mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19570/how-to-cite-author-date-including-page-number-in-org-mode)* - to achieve the citation with page number you have to type `[[cite:lewis_plurality_2001][100]]`

The problem is that it will be virtually impossible to write a paper where you have to stop and square bracket every reference in that way. So I'm wondering if there isn't an easier way to do this with `org-ref` that I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the bibtex key you want to cite then you can use `org-insert-link` to do this. Usually that is bound to C-c C-l, you will be prompted for what kind of link, you can choose cite (the capitalization is a little annoying and you might have to figure out how to not get Cite with this. I use ivy, and I have to toggle the case sensitivity, and search for ^cite: to get what I want.), then use completion to select the bibtex key, then you will be prompted for the description.

If you want the completion on the title/author etc, you need to make a new function like this

```
(defun harvard-cite (key page)
  (interactive (list (completing-read "Cite: " (orhc-bibtex-candidates))
             (read-string "Page: ")))


  (insert
   (org-make-link-string (format "cite:%s"
                 (cdr (assoc
                       "=key="
                       (cdr (assoc key (orhc-bibtex-candidates))))))
             page)))
```

Then, you can bind it to a convenient key and get on with your writing.

Comment: Thank you so much Professor Kitchin - didn't expect I'd be getting an answer directly from you! 

`org-insert-link` is exactly what I was looking for and works pretty much perfectly. But the `harvard-cite` function is the cherry on top and is just that much faster b/c you don't have to select the citation type first. For some reason though my `orhc-bibtex-candidates` was empty so I also had to evaluate `(setq org-ref-bibtex-files '("references.bib"))`

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to mention another possible way of doing this, building on what Professor Kitchin said. I am also a complete lisp noob so this may violate lisp intergalactic laws I am not aware of, be that as it may - the function does seem to work for me.

The `harvard-cite` function works near perfectly fine just by itself. The only other thing I had to do to get it running was add `(setq org-ref-bibtex-files '("bibliography.bib"))` to my `~/.emacs` otherwise my `orhc-bibtex-candidates` would be empty.

As it is the function will use only a single citation type with a page number, but if you also listen for an ivy prefix arg, then you can do a `M-X harvard-cite` and when hovering over an entry hit `C-u` to choose a different citation type. But if you just hit `RET` your default citation link will be used.

After reading
https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2016/06/14/Using-prefix-args-in-ivy-actions/ I somehow managed to modify the function to do just that. And with the code below you can select an alternate citation with `C-u RET`.

```lisp
(setq org-ref-bibtex-files '("bibliography.bib")) ;; replace with your default bib file
(defun harvard-cite (entry page)
  (interactive (list (completing-read "Cite: "
                                      (orhc-bibtex-candidates))
                     (read-string "Page: ")))
  (setq key (cdr (assoc "=key=" (cdr (assoc entry (orhc-bibtex-candidates))))))
  (setq type (if ivy-current-prefix-arg
                 (ivy-read "type: " org-ref-cite-types)
                 org-ref-default-citation-link))
  (insert (org-make-link-string (format "%s:%s" type key) page)))
```